# Spacing between footnotes similar to spacing in footnote

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, setspace

I add line spacing to my main text with `\setstretch{1.18}` and to footnotes with `\setstretch{1.22`}. When there are multiple footnotes on a page I of course want the spacing between the last line of one and the first line of the next to be the same as between lines in the same footnote. By eyesight I have more or less achieved this with `\setlength{\footnotesep}{.59\baselineskip}`.

Is there a way to do this automatically and exactly?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.18}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{.59\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\footnote{\setstretch{1.22}#1}}
\newcommand{\lorum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lorum\note{\lorum}

\lorum\note{\lorum}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to use anything but singlespacing in the footnotes?

Comment: @Mico Because there needs to be enough space for some mathematical notation that has symbols under the main line.

Comment: In case there are some such mathematical notation, LaTeX will enlarge the spacing automatically.

Comment: @JouleV Yes, but non-uniformly, which I think is ugly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just multiply the standard `\footnotesep` by 1.22:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.18}
\setlength{\footnotesep}{1.22\footnotesep}
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\footnote{\setstretch{1.22}#1}}

\newcommand{\lorum}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
  adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
  adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}

\begin{document}

\lorum\note{\lorum}

\lorum\note{\lorum}

\end{document}
```

[image]